# TiKz: Text inside circles overlaps

Tags: tikz-pgf

How can I fit the text squarely inside the circles without it overlapping like this?
[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
   %\usepgfplotslibrary{external}
%\tikzexternalize
\begin{document}
\def\firstcircle{(90:1cm) circle (2.5cm)}
  \def\secondcircle{(210:2.5cm) circle (2.5cm)}
  \def\thirdcircle{(330:2.5cm) circle (2.5cm)}
  \def\fourthcircle{(90:-3.5cm) circle (2.5cm)}
%\tikzsetnextfilename{4way_venn}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}[ fill opacity=0.5]
        \fill[red] \firstcircle;
        \fill[green] \secondcircle;
        \fill[blue] \thirdcircle;
    \fill[cyan] \fourthcircle;\end{scope}
%    \begin{scope}
%      \clip \firstcircle;
%      \clip \secondcircle;
%      \clip \thirdcircle;
%\fill[cyan]\fourthcircle;
%    \end{scope}
      \draw \firstcircle node[text=black,above] {CO$_2$ reduction};
      \draw \secondcircle node [text=black, left=1cm] {Cost-effectiveness};
      \draw \thirdcircle node [text=black,right=-0.4cm] {Infection control};
\draw \fourthcircle node [text=black,below=1cm]{Customer satisfaction};

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is it allowed to overlap with the inner circles?

Comment: Preferably it should only cover its own circle.

Comment: Ok, then I won't submit it as an answer. A quick workaround to get rid of the overlapping in your case is to tweak the `left=1cm` option, reducing it a little. That's what is pushing the text so far left. But I understand that you would prefer an automagical solution. `:)`

Comment: @T.Verron ah yes the joy and simplicity of automagic! I see what you are referring to though. In fact I had to place those circles in a rather ad-hoc trial and error way. I would have liked to just position, say the top one, and have the rest fall into place...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you fix a certain `width` to your text, then an `align` option breaks long lines according the width. A possible `manual` solution for your example would be:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
   %\usepgfplotslibrary{external}
%\tikzexternalize
\begin{document}
\def\firstcircle{(90:1cm) circle (2.5cm)}
  \def\secondcircle{(210:2.5cm) circle (2.5cm)}
  \def\thirdcircle{(330:2.5cm) circle (2.5cm)}
  \def\fourthcircle{(90:-3.5cm) circle (2.5cm)}
%\tikzsetnextfilename{4way_venn}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}[ fill opacity=0.5]
        \fill[red] \firstcircle;
        \fill[green] \secondcircle;
        \fill[blue] \thirdcircle;
    \fill[cyan] \fourthcircle;\end{scope}
%    \begin{scope}
%      \clip \firstcircle;
%      \clip \secondcircle;
%      \clip \thirdcircle;
%\fill[cyan]\fourthcircle;
%    \end{scope}
      \draw \firstcircle node[text=black,above, text width=2cm, align=center] {CO$_2$ reduction};
      \draw \secondcircle node [text=black, left, text width=2cm, align=center] {Cost-effectiveness};
      \draw \thirdcircle node [text=black,right, text width=2cm, align=center] {Infection control};
\draw \fourthcircle node [text=black,below, text width=2cm, align=center]{Customer satisfaction};

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]